# I would like to remove seconds and milliseconds from my date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For now, I post my date like this:

17:34:14.965

I would only have the hours and minutes.
How to do ?

Comment: `var dt ="17:34:14.965"; dt.slice(0, dt.lastIndexOf(":"))`

Comment: @JaromandaX— *Data.prototype*? Is that ECMAScript 2018? ;-)

Comment: damn my typos!!! :p

Comment: How is this an `AngularJS` issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert String to the Date Object. And then extract whatever format you want

```
  $scope.time = '17:34:14.965';
  var timeTokens = $scope.time.split(':');
  var newDate= new Date(1970, 0, 1, timeTokens[0], timeTokens[1], timeTokens[2]);
  $scope.hourAndMin = $filter('date')(newDate, 'HH:mm');
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.time = '17:34:14.965';
  var timeTokens = $scope.time.split(':');
  var newDate= new Date(1970, 0, 1, timeTokens[0], timeTokens[1], timeTokens[2]);
  $scope.hourAndMin = $filter('date')(newDate, 'HH:mm');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{hourAndMin}}
</div>
```

Comment: Mark as the answer for future user reference.

Answer (score 6):

you can do in this way

```
var date="17:34:14.965";

var splittedString=date.split(":");

date=splittedString.slice(0,-1).join(':');
```

reference [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) , [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Replace with a regular expression will do the job:

```js
var dateString = '17:34:14.965'
console.log( dateString.replace(/:[^:]*$/,'') );
```